# NextJS with next-auth, doesn't receive cookies from backend

Tags: typescript, next.js, nestjs, next-auth

I have a Next frontend, and a Nest backend.

I'm using **next-auth in the frontend** like this:

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Username",
          type: "text",
          value: "antalmate12@gmail.com",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          value: "12312356",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials || !credentials.username || !credentials.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const { username, password } = credentials;
        const authResponse = await fetch(
          // FIXME: use process.env.BACKEND_URL
          "http://localhost:3001/api/auth/login",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
          }
        );

        // Log all cookies from the response
        console.log("COOKIES FROM NEST BACKEND:");
        const tokenString: string | null =
          authResponse.headers.get("set-cookie");

        if (tokenString !== null) {
          // Get the 'accessToken' and 'refreshToken' from the response's cookies
          const accessTokenMatch = tokenString.match(/accessToken=([^;]+)/);
          const refreshTokenMatch = tokenString.match(/refreshToken=([^;]+)/);

          const accessToken = accessTokenMatch ? accessTokenMatch[1] : null;
          const refreshToken = refreshTokenMatch ? refreshTokenMatch[1] : null;

          if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
            console.log("COOKIES FROM NEST BACKEND:");
            console.log({
              accessToken,
              refreshToken,
            });

            // Set the cookies, they should never expire
            setCookie(null, "accessToken", accessToken, {
              maxAge: 2147483647,
              path: "/",
              httpOnly: true,
            });

            setCookie(null, "refreshToken", refreshToken, {
              maxAge: 2147483647,
              path: "/",
              httpOnly: true,
            });
          }
        }

        if (!authResponse.ok) {
          return null;
        }

        const user = await authResponse.json();
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  // trustHost: true,

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          ...user,
        };
      }

      if (new Date().getTime() < token.tokens.expiresIn) return token;

      return await refreshToken(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      session.tokens = token.tokens;
      return session;
      // return {
      //   ...session,
      //   user: token,
      // };
    },
    // async session({ session, token }) {
    //   // session.user = {
    //   //   ...token.user,
    //   //   emailVerified: new Date(),
    //   // };
    //   session.tokens = token.tokens;

    //   return session;
    // },
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

In the **Backend**, I have this **login route**:

```
@UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post("login")
  async login(@Request() req) {
    const res = await this.authService.login(req.user);

    // Set the cookie in the response
    req.res.cookie("accessToken", res.tokens.accessToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      path: "/",
      domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "todo.something" : "localhost",
      secure: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365),
      sameSite: 'Lax',
    });

    req.res.cookie("refreshToken", res.tokens.refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      path: "/",
      domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "todo.something" : "localhost",
      secure: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365),
      sameSite: 'Lax',
    });

    return res;
  }
```

My problem is that the FE doesn't get the access and refresh tokens, I tried calling it via a dummy button as well, I could see the cookies in the request, but in the "Application" tab of the devtools the cookies are not added, only those that are generated by next-auth.

In the **BE.** i guard the routes with a **jwt strategy** that tries to extract the auth token either as a Bearer token from the headers (client call), or from the cookies (server call).

In **FE.** in the **authorize** call I can access those cookies, I've even tried to save them from there, but they still won't appear in the devtools.

What am I doing wrong? Should I even stick with next-auth, or should I just implement FE authentication on my own?

**Edit:**.

**The login request returns with data like this:**

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "firstName",
        "lastName": "lastName",
        "userName": "userName",
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "profilePicture": null
    },
    "tokens": {
        "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1Ni...",
        "refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpX...",
        "expiresIn": 1708896682335
    }
}
```